# IIS configuring with weblogic

Tags: iis, weblogic

I am trying to configure IIS with weblogic, where my application is running on weblogic.
I have searched for many documents online, found few, but not able to configure successfully.
Can anyone, please give me the exact steps on how to configure it.

Thanks in Advance
Siva

Comment: you should ask questions about configuring server software on http://serverfault.com rather than here. stackoverflow is more about programming.

Comment: Agree with Pavel but you also need to provide more information on what you have tried/what errors you are encountering. There are lots of tutorials out there like: http://www.gitshah.com/2013/06/how-to-use-iis7-as-front-end-to-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's some urls about how to configure iis as a proxy to wls using wlplugin.

http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/11/12/configuring-iis-with-weblogic-server/
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e14395/isapi.htm
http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2012/10/03/configure-iis7-as-a-proxy-with-weblogic-server/

share your configuration, and tell us more about the errors you are getting, then we might be able to help you further.